# Is purity an entanglement witness?

Tags: entanglement-witness

Suppose an n-qubit mixed state $\rho$
with subsystems $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$

If purity of an arbitrary qubit $a_i$ is 1, then can i conclude its separatable from the entire system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an entanglement witness for two reasons:

1. Entanglement witnesses are linear maps in $\rho$. $\mathrm{tr}\,\rho^2$ is not a linear map.
2. Entanglement witnesses, by definition, detect entanglement in general (i.e., mixed) quantum states. This is not the case for the purity of a subsystem, as e.g. the maximally mixed and maximally entangled state have the same purity on each subsystem.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an entanglement witness per se. A subsystem having purity = 1 does mean it is separable, i.e., it is a product state with the rest of the system. However, a subsystem having purity $\neq$ 1 does not mean it is always entangled. See a counter-example [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/35653/25170). The exception for this is when your initial system of $n$ qubits is a pure state. See more [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2266/25170).